# Simulating real key strokes on an inactive webrowser control

Tags: c#, angularjs, winforms, webbrowser-control, keystroke

I have a C# winforms app with a WebBrowser control embedded for website automation. I need to **send programatically keyboard strokes** from within the app to the embedded WebBrowser control **even when the app is hidden or not focused**. Setting text to HTML text boxes normally works but sometimes not (i.e. an HTML form with AngularJS validation ignores it as it's not real typing I suppose).

I've spent 2 weeks searching and trying different approches:

- SendInput or SendKeys: works fine only when the app is foregrounded (not good).
- Raising OnKeyDown and OnKeyPress events: not working for me at the form level and at WebBrowser control level.
- Raising keydown,keypress, keyup events with JQuery in the DOM: No success.

Is there at all any solution to this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error found a solution. AngularJS form validation mechanism waits for "change" event to happen (and not for keydown,keyup,keypress). To trigger this event wasn't easy (JQuery.trigger didn't do the job). I injected the following function in the WebBrowser control and then invoked it.

```js
setInputText = function (id, str, x) {
    var el = $('#' + id);
    if (typeof x === "undefined") {
        x = 0;
        el.focus();
    }
    if (x >= str.length) { 
        el.blur();
        return;
    }
    
    var c = str.charAt(x);
    el.val(el.val() + c);

    //This is the magic: trigger change event in pure JS
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
    el[0].dispatchEvent(evt);        

    //type each character every 75ms
    setTimeout(function () { setInputText(id, str, ++x); }, 75);
    return;
}
```